# Advice about the book "Problem from the book" Titu Andreescu

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am training for math olympiad and I do exercise from old contest and I have read some book. I read for example Modern Olympiad Number Theory
Aditya Khurmi, Evan Chen geometry book, Olympiad
Combinatorics
Pranav A. Sriram, Zdravko Cvetkovski
Inequalities
Theorems, Techniques
and Selected Problems... and other book.

I have heard that this book is good and very advanced. Before buy it I ask if it is a good book for my training and if with book that I read I am ready: what are the prerequisites?
Thanks.
I am sorry for my bad english,

Comment: The prerequisites differ from chapter to chapter and from example to example. If you are at the level of IMO 2/5, you'll find much of it readable, and at least in my view it's very much worth reading. (Same applies to the sequel "Straight from the Book".)

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are training for Mathematics Olympiads, I have read or seen some other books that may help you.

They include:

The IMO Compendium (2nd edition) (Dusan Djukic, Vladmir Jankovic, Ivan Matic, Nikola Petrovic) - A book full of IMO problems and solutions from 1959-2009 with key mathematical concepts before them. In my opinion, having read and tried some of the problems, a great book to at least try and gauge your mathematical level.

Problem-Solving Strategies (1997/1999 edition) (Arthur Engel) - A training book with problems and solutions from over 20 different major national and international mathematical competitions. I have not personally read this book but I have heard from other people that it is a great book and one to try your hands at.

There are so many more - whenever I want to find a new book on this, I normally search 'mathematical Olympiad preparation books' on Google.

Another way to find books like these is to find PDF lists by schools or institutions - they are normally a good and reliable source.

One final way to find them is to go onto Amazon or any other bookshop's website and use filters to find them.

Good luck with your training!

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, it will be very useful for my training!